# Wrap elements and content into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am requesting data (with jQuery `load()` function) from another site into my `<div class="ajax-container">` to display the gathered data. Data comes with elements AND content (only text, like "born 2007"). I have tried to wrap these with jQuery `wrap()` and `wrapAll` method, but it doesn't wrap it correctly. So I want to wrap all elements and content into a single `div` so I can style it more easily.

How can I achieve this? I need to wrap everything UNTIL certain `class` is found. I've also tried jQuery `parentsUntil()` method but that didn't work either. I have no idea how to achieve this so I need your help.

Example data (html that prints to my page):

```
<div class="container">
    <b class="big_text">Title</b>
    "some content after title&nbsp;"
    <b>Subtitle content here</b>
    <br />
    <span class="no-wrap"><b>Price</b></span>
    <br />
    "made in 2007"
    <div class="picture">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

So that's the problem, I have to wrap everything into a `div` until `<div class="picture">` appears.

This did not work:

```
 $(".container").children().nextUntil(".picture").wrapAll("<div></div>");
```

This would be the desired result:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
    <b class="big_text">Title</b>
    "some content after title&nbsp;"
    <b>Subtitle content here</b>
    <br />
    <span class="no-wrap"><b>Price</b></span>
    <br />
    "made in 2007"
</div>
<div class="picture">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add example data and example final HTML to your question?

Comment: @ChrisG added the template now

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "wrap eveything in a div until `<div class="picture">` appears. Can you provide an example of your desired result.

Comment: @ChrisG I want to wrap everything, every element and content until the `<div class="picture">`. I mean, don't wrap the picture to anything, but all the siblings of container before it. The desired result I wish for is to set the content next to picture, not above it (now the elements and text are above the picture, leaving much space for right without use.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best approach is to wrap the inner contents then move "picture":

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".container").wrapInner("<div></div>");
  $(".container").append($(".container .picture"));
})
```

```css
.container > div ~ .picture {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <b class="big_text">Title</b>
    "some content after title&nbsp;"
    <b>Subtitle content here</b>
    <br />
    <span class="no-wrap"><b>Price</b></span>
    <br />
    "made in 2007"
    <div class="picture">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```